# Issue with docker compose

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

The issue I am having is that after I try and run docker-compose up, after everything is downloaded(python dependencies) docker-compose will just hang on

```
Recreating sensorarray_web_1...
Attaching to sensorarray_web_1
```

My directory structure looks like like this:

```
.
 ├── docker-compose.yml
 ├── Dockerfile
 ├── requirements.txt
 └── sensoryarray.py
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code
CMD python sensorarray.py
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
 build: .
 command: python sensorarray.py
ports:
 - "5000:5000"
volumes:
 - .:/code
```

sensoryarray.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

I also ran the docker hello world example and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: What do you mean "hang"? If you want your terminal back, run `docker-compose -d`, otherwise docker-compose will attach to the containers and print the logs.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? Running into it now too.

Comment: No I still do not have this figured out, I abandoned docker compose, because of this issue. Adrian, my understanding is that there would be more output from starting the docker container, I mean it literally will hang forever on Attaching to sensorarray_web_1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured I would try updating this evening to the latest docker-composer (1.2.0) and everything just kind of started working. I am still not sure what the problem was. However if someone lands on this page and is still running 1.1.0, I would suggest updating.

Comment: :( this is happening to me on docker-compose version: 1.4.1

Comment: I downgraded to 1.4.0 and it worked like a charm. Seems to have been a blunder by the devs: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2067

Comment: had the same problem with 1.4.1 (downloaded last friday); after downgrading to 1.4.0 everything works fine!